# Pandas: multiple histograms of categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Type       Cat1       Cat2       Cat3
0   A      0.384000   0.393000   0.458000
1   B      0.603337   0.381470   0.299773
2   C      0.585797   0.452570   0.317607
3   D      0.324715   0.765212   0.717755
```

I want to produce three histograms, one for each "Cat". Each histogram must show the values for each "Type" (e.g., the categories) as x labels on the bottom histogram.

I have been trying to do this using `df.plot(kind='hist')` but to no avail:

```
ax=df.plot(kind='hist',subplots=True,layout=(3,1),title='My title',color='orange',grid=True,legend=False)
```

but I see that:

1. The x axis does not show the four types, but just a bunch of numbers
2. The y axis ranges from 0 to 4, while it must go from 0 to 1 (these are frequencies)
3. Only one bar is shown in each subplot

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

The wrong painting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:
you don't want a histogram, you just want a bar plot.

```
df.set_index('Type').plot.bar(subplots=True, legend=False)
```

[image]

---

adjust vertical spacing assuming `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

```
axes = df.set_index('Type').plot.bar(subplots=True, legend=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry this looks harder than I thought. How can I modify the y range of each subplot? They need be different.

Comment: `matplotlib` has tons of features to tweak.  This should be treated as a different question.

Comment: You are right. The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807091/pandas-set-different-ylim-for-different-subplots.