# Pandas: set different ylim and titles for different subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

Say I have this dataframe:

```
    Type       Cat1       Cat2       Cat3
0   A      0.384000   0.393000   0.458000
1   B      0.603337   0.381470   0.299773
2   C      0.585797   0.452570   0.317607
3   D      0.324715   0.765212   0.717755
```

That I plot like this ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805910/pandas-multiple-histograms-of-categorical-data?answertab=active#tab-top)):

```
axes = df.set_index('Type').plot.bar(subplots=True, legend=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
```

[image]

**My problem:** how can I set a different `ylim` for each subplot? And how can I modify things like the font size of the `Cat` titles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the plotting method returns an array of axes in your `axes` variable.  You can access each one and set the title and ylim.

```
axes = df.set_index('Type').plot.bar(subplots=True, legend=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
axes[0].set_ylim(0, 1.1)
axes[0].set_title('hello')
```

[image]